# syntax error with cocoon and Rails 4 nested forms with formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax, formtastic, cocoon-gem

I'm sure this is one of those dumb things where if I were pair-coding, my partner would be like, "Hey, dummy, you need to close that bracket there." But anyway, I'd love an extra set of eyes on this.

Here's the main form:

```
<%= semantic_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<div id="user-general">
  <%= f.inputs :first_name, :last_name, :email, :is_female %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :date_of_birth, :as => :date_picker %>
    <%= f.input :hire_date, :as => :date_picker %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
  <div id="user-jobs">
    <%= f.semantic_fields_for :jobs do |job|%>
      <%= render 'job_fields', f => job %> 
    <% end %>
    <div class='links'>
      <%= link_to_add_association 'Add a job', f, :jobs %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>
  <%= f.actions do %>
    <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

And the partial for the nested elements:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
    <%= f.inputs do %>
        <%= f.input :niche, :label => 'Job' %> at <%= f.input :theater, :as => :select, :collection => Theater.all, :label_method => :name %> on <%= f.input :production, :as => :select, :collection => Production.all, :label_method => :name %>
        <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove Job", f %><br /> 
    <% end %>
</div>
```

And the error:

```
/home/alisha/code/git-henslowe/Henslowe/app/views/users/_job_fields.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_end
... f.input :niche, :label => 'Job' );@output_buffer.safe_conca...
...                               ^
/home/alisha/code/git-henslowe/Henslowe/app/views/users/_job_fields.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
...@output_buffer.safe_concat(' at ');@output_buffer.append= ( ...
...                               ^
/home/alisha/code/git-henslowe/Henslowe/app/views/users/_job_fields.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
...@output_buffer.safe_concat(' on ');@output_buffer.append= ( ...
...                               ^
/home/alisha/code/git-henslowe/Henslowe/app/views/users/_job_fields.erb:4: syntax error, unexpected tREGEXP_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
...utput_buffer.safe_concat('<br /> 
...                               ^
/home/alisha/code/git-henslowe/Henslowe/app/views/users/_job_fields.erb:6: unknown regexp options - dv
unmatched close parenthesis: /> 
');  end 
@output_buffer.safe_concat('</i
/home/alisha/code/git-henslowe/Henslowe/app/views/users/_job_fields.erb:6: unterminated string meets end of file
/home/alisha/code/git-henslowe/Henslowe/app/views/users/_job_fields.erb:6: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Extracted source (around line #3):

1: <div class="nested-fields">
2:  <%= f.inputs do %>
3:      <%= f.input :niche, :label => 'Job' %> at <%= f.input :theater, :as => :select, :collection => Theater.all, :label_method => :name %> on <%= f.input :production, :as => :select, :collection => Production.all, :label_method => :name %>
4:      <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove Job", f %><br /> 
5:  <% end %>
6: </div>
```

When I remove the call to the partial, the error goes away--and, oddly, I can use the "Add job" button, which also calls the partial, no problem.

This seems to only be an issue when the partial also needs to return a record that has data in it, but the data is all benign, no () or "" or anything like that that should be escaped. I'm confused, and I'm sure there's something super basic that I'm missing.

Interestingly, this works:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
    <%= f.inputs do %>
        <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove Job", f %><br /> 
    <% end %>
</div>
```

but this doesn't:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
    <%= f.inputs do %>
        <%= f.input :niche %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

And neither does this:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
    <%= f.inputs do %>
        <%= f.input :theater %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

So, it's somewhere in that inputs section. But no idea what's wrong. I had this working as a straight formtastic pre-cocoon, btw, with the inputs coded exactly this way.

Comment: In your code the render line is wrong: it says `<%= render 'job_fields', f => job %>`, you should be using the symbol `:f` instead.